# What is the standard cXML way of sending shipment method in a purchase order?

Tags: cxml-commercexml

In cXML, was is the correct and expected way to specify the requested shipping method and carrier for a purchase order? For example, how would I request USPS Priority Mail?

It seems to require a mixture of `ShipTo > CarrierIdentifier` **and** `Shipping > Description`. But even the official user guide seems to have a mismatch (UPS and FedEx 2-day)...

`<OrderRequestHeader>
    ...
    <ShipTo>
        <Address>
            ...
        </Address>
        <CarrierIdentifier domain="companyName">UPS</CarrierIdentifier>
    </ShipTo>
    ...
    <Shipping>
        ...
        <Description xml:lang="en-US">FedEx 2-day</Description>
    </Shipping>
    ...
</OrderRequestHeader>`

Answer (score 0):

To some degree, we can't answer this, because it will have to be decided between you and your trading partner.

That said, the Shipping block is a money item...the Description can be anything, but typically has something to express how the amount was determined, in your example the amount represents what would be charged for FedEx 2-day.  In your ShipTo, that's where you specify the carrier you want to be used. Some trading partners have a specific set of codes they're expecting in the domain or element value or both...ask them.

Finally, note that within ShipTo you also have a TransportationInformation element that you and your trading partner might find useful.

Comment: Thanks, The `TransportInformation.Route` values are limited to `air`, `rail` `motor` and `ship`, so we cannot really use that either.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding two `<CarrierIdentifier>` nodes, with two different domain attributes. I believe it to be the correct implementation as the DTD supports multiple `<CarrierIdentifier>` in the `<ShipTo>` node.

`<ShipTo>
   <Address>
    ...
   </Address>
   <CarrierIdentifier domain="carrier">USPS</CarrierIdentifier>
   <CarrierIdentifier domain="shipMethod">Priority</CarrierIdentifier>
</ShipTo>`